# Length of parametric curve $\phi(t)=(f(t)\cos(t),f(t)\sin(t))$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, parametric, curves

> Define the curve $\phi$ by $\phi(t):=(f(t)\cos(t),f(t)\sin(t))$, where $f$ be a strictly increasing infinitly many differentiable function . Find an explicit formula for the length of $\phi$ between $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$.

By using the definition of the length of a curve, you could reduce the problem to compute the integral $$\int_a^b \sqrt{f'(x)^2 + f(x)^2} dx $$
But now tricks by change of variables and integration by parts seems not to be helpful. Probably this integral cannot be computed explicitly in terms of antiderivatives.

Comment: by numerical methods ?

Comment: A context for this problem would be helpful. Where does this come from?

Comment: @darya khosrotash: It should be non-numerical methods (i.e. by manipulations of integrals such as change of variables and integration by parts.

Comment: Sorry, the context is to compute the length of the curve $\phi$ defined by $\phi(t):=(f(t)cos(t),f(t)sin(t))$. Should one consider this problem geometrically?

Comment: One cannot expect a "universal"  method for computing antiderivatives of such complicated expressions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes you are probably right. I reformulate the whole post. I was sure, that this was the right way to deal with the original problem.

Comment: I think of the expression as an integral as the explicit formula.

Comment: many strictly increasing $f(x)$ seem to return no antiderivative in terms of elementary functions for example $f(x)=ln(x)%$ or $f(x)=arctan(x)$. It may be noted that for many funtions the $sqrt(f(x)^2+f'(x)^2)$ has asymptotic behaviour with $f(x)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I think you are again probably right. 
Should I delete the post? Should I answer my own question?

Comment: Answering your own question is always a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $$\int_a^b \sqrt{f'(x)^2 + f(x)^2} dx $$ was meant as a solution.